# Use the Stop Filter with stopword_path on Elasticsearch.net, Nest

Tags: nest

how can i use the stop filter... with stopword_path ??
i can use the stop filter  in postman

this is my code here.

```
    "analysis" : {
    "analyzer" : {
        "ilhee_Custom" : {
            "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                "filter" : ["lowercase", "my_stoplist"]
                 }
            },
    "filter" : {
         "my_stoplist" : {
            "type" : "stop",
                "stopwords_path" : "stopword_list.txt",
                    "remove_trailing" : true
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

---

### i find the answer!! is it..right?

```
     var stoplist = new StopTokenFilterDescriptor();
        stoplist.StopWordsPath(@"\stopword_list.txt");   
       var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("ilhee", c => c
        .Settings(s => s
         .Analysis(a => a
          .Analyzers(ad => ad       
           // give the custom analyzer a name
           .Custom("ilhee_Custom", ca => ca
            .Tokenizer("standard")
            .Filters("lowercase", "stop", "standard", "snowball","my_stoplist")
           )
          )
          .TokenFilters(s1=>s1
          .UserDefined("my_stoplist",stoplist))
            )       
         )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that will work. You can also use the `Stop()` method on `TokenFiltersDescriptor`

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("ilhee", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(ad => ad
                // give the custom analyzer a name
                .Custom("ilhee_Custom", ca => ca
                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                    .Filters("lowercase", "stop", "standard", "snowball", "my_stoplist")
                )
            )
            .TokenFilters(s1 => s1
                .Stop("my_stoplist", tf => tf
                    .StopWordsPath("stopword_list.txt")
                )
            )
        )   
    )
);
```

[Path is relative to `config` location or an absolute path.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html)

Comment: yes i know the config locaion!  i see the elasticsearch doc page !
thank you !!